# Completely Disable Safari Only Mode in Lion

Tags: macos, safari, network

I'm wondering if there is a way to completely disable Safari Only mode so users cannot access it at all. I administer a network here at this business and we have internet filters on all/most of the computers here. The problem is that Safari Only mode would pose an obvious loop hole in that. I really need to be able to completely disable that before upgrading the computers to Lion. I would secure the internet at the network but I don't want to workers taking work computers home with them without filters.

I'm very willing to go beyond "settings" if I need to. Is there a good way to more or less "delete" this feature from Lion?

I've heard that if the Recovery Partition fails to load that Safari Only mode will also not work, but I think the Recovery Partition is read only, and I don't think I can change that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out today!

Here's what I did.

1. I downloaded and installed Lion from the Mac App Store.
2. I then used the [Lion Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433) to put the recovery partition on a USB flash drive. You can test it by restarting your machine while the flash drive is plugged in, holding <kbd>option</kbd> and selecting the USB drive on the boot menu. This should take you to the Lion Recovery Disk Assistant on the flash drive.
3. Since Safari Only Mode uses the built in recovery partition, removing it resolves this issue. [This guide](http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/30/deleting-the-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-recovery-hd-partition/) shows you how to delete the recovery partition.

And voila! Everything should boot up nice and pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General and check "Disable restarting to Safari when screen is locked"

Comment: But can't a user just go in and un-check that? Seems they just uncheck, reboot, and are in to Safari. It is really important that they each be the admin of the computer so they can install software and such.

Comment: @bassplayer7 It depends on whether or not the user is an administrator on the machine they are using. If they are not, they won't be able to adjust this setting without authenticating as an administrator.